# Regex get text between first p tags

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to edit the Original code to get the first p tag from product.description and tried the New Code, but with no success. Is there another method anyone can recommend? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Original Code:
if (quickview.find('.des').length > 0) {          
  var description = product.description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
  quickview.find('.des').text(description);
}

New Code:
if (quickview.find('.des').length > 0) {
    var description = product.description.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, "");
    quickview.find('.des').text(description);
}
```

Example parse for New Code:

```
<p>First inner content needed.</p> <p>content...</p> <span>content...</span>
```

I'm trying to grab everything inside the first paragraph only and need to remove all p tags and any other tags after.

Comment: What is `quickview.find()`?

Comment: `product.description` appears to be a string, not a DOM element. `getElementsByTagName` is an element method.

Comment: It seems like you're expecting `getElementsByTagName` to parse the HTML string. It won't do that. You could create a `documentFragment` whose innerHTML is `product.description` and then use `getElementsByTagName` on that.

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML that your JavaScript is operating on. In your New Code you have a statement: ```description = description```. It is difficult (for me anyway) to understand how that could be useful as it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (quickview.find('.des').length > 0) {                    
  var description = product.description.match(/<p class="desQuickView">(.*?)<\/p>/g, "").map(function(val){
       return val.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
  });
  quickview.find('.des').text(description);
```

I found a way to target my first paragraph by adding a class name. Then I look for all tags and replaced them with an empty strings.